# Как с помощью js вытащить id дива

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

Есть несколько дивов(их количество зависит от длинны листа)

```
 <div class="inbox_chat">
                <c:forEach items="${allLoginUser}" var="user">
                    <div class="chat_list" id="${user.id}">
                        <div class="chat_people">
                            <div class="chat_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png"
                                                       alt="sunil"></div>
                            <div class="chat_ib">
                                <h5>${user.login}<span class="chat_date"><% new Date(); %></span></h5>
                                <p>Тут наверное будет последнее сообщение</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </c:forEach>
            </div>
```

Т.е. получается, что каждый див уникален его id это id пользователя. Я хочу написать js функцию, чтобы мне этот id отправлять на сервак при клике.
Вопрос как мне в моей функции получить этот id:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('#chat_list_ID ???').click(function () {
            //do something
           //send server userName + chat_list_ID на котороый нажали
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот этот селектор выберет все `div` с классом `chat_list`

```
$('div.chat_list')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('div.chat_list').click(function () {
        let id = this.id;
        console.log(id)
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inbox_chat">
              
        <div class="chat_list" id="id1">
            <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png"
                                           alt="sunil"></div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                    <h5>${user.login}<span class="chat_date">111</span></h5>
                    <p>Тут наверное будет последнее сообщение</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat_list" id="id2">
            <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png"
                                           alt="sunil"></div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                    <h5>${user.login}<span class="chat_date">111</span></h5>
                    <p>Тут наверное будет последнее сообщение</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="chat_list" id="id3">
            <div class="chat_people">
                <div class="chat_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png"
                                           alt="sunil"></div>
                <div class="chat_ib">
                    <h5>${user.login}<span class="chat_date">111</span></h5>
                    <p>Тут наверное будет последнее сообщение</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chat_list').click(function () {
        var id = this.id;
        //send server userName + chat_list_ID на котороый нажали
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
       $('.chat_list').click(function () {
            //do something
           //send server userName + chat_list_ID на котороый нажали
           alert($(this).attr('id'));
       });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inbox_chat">
                    <div class="chat_list" id="user1">
                        <div class="chat_people">
                            <div class="chat_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png"
                                                       alt="sunil"></div>
                            <div class="chat_ib">
                                <h5>user1<span class="chat_date">date1</span></h5>
                                <p>сообщение1</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="chat_list" id="user2">
                        <div class="chat_people">
                            <div class="chat_img"><img src="https://ptetutorials.com/images/user-profile.png"
                                                       alt="sunil"></div>
                            <div class="chat_ib">
                                <h5>user2<span class="chat_date">date2</span></h5>
                                <p>сообщение2</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```